# Leaving multiple parameters to their default values in python functions

Tags: python

How is it possible to leave a subset of the input parameters of a function to their default values in python?

For example,

```
>>> def sum(a=2, b=3):
...   print a + b

>>> sum(1,2)
3

>>> sum(1)
4
```

How can I leave **a** as 2 and only change **b**'s value? Something like:

```
sum(_,4) # a is 2 and b 4, and sum should print 6
```

Comment: You could also do it like this: `sum(sum.func_defaults[0],4)` if you remember the position of the parameters. However, `mysum(b=4)` is simply better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass `b` as a keyword argument to the function:

```
>>> def mysum(a=2, b=3):
...     print a + b
... 
>>> mysum(b=4)
6
```

Read about keyword arguments [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the name of the one parameter you want to change an its new value, and don't specify the ones you don't change.

```
sum(b=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if the object is immutable, the value of the parameters don't change on every function call, unless it is specified otherwise. If a defaut parameter is defined, you can change only the default parameter that you specify at function call, as this:

```
>>> sum(b=4)
6
```